# Error Code 2002 with Plaid + Stripe Api

Tags: javascript, api, stripe-payments, banking, plaid

Has anyone gotten this error code message:

```
{errorcode":2002,"message":"unable to generate bank account token","resolve":"The bank account token could not be generated. Try again.","statusCode":400}
```

I have went through the possible steps to fix this error, in this article I found via plaid api dos: https://support.plaid.com/customer/en/portal/articles/2522325-plaid-stripe-troubleshooting

1) I made sure that my Stripe account approves and is authorized to handle ACH transfers, and

2) I made sure that my Plaid and Stripe account are connected

I have reached out to both Plaid and Stripe ... Stripe has gotten back, but Plaid is a little slow at times. Stripe did confirm however that from their end my account looks great, and also confirmed that it was properly connected with Plaid.

Has anyone else had this issue, and have found a fix for it? Other than what that article above suggested it could be.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally received an answer to this problem, and I'm just going to post it here in case someone else ever stumbles into this problem. Hopefully this will be helpful!

So, although their documentation as a lot of examples with this as the solution it was never really explicitly stated, but you have to use **Plaid's Auth product** when doing Plaid + Stripe integration. Then upgrade your user to have access to Connect, if that is the one you are after.

Hope this helps someone down the road!

Answer (score 0):

With the Plaid + Stripe integration, you should make sure that the "product" field in Plaid Link is set to Auth!

You shouldn't need to send the upgrade request to Connect unless you are interested in pulling down transaction data from the user's account for the product that you're building.

Plaid + Stripe docs can be found here:
https://plaid.com/docs/link/stripe/#step-1-set-up-your-plaid-and-stripe-accounts